# Test IHostedService with IHostApplicationLifetime

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, nunit

I'm trying to write unit tests for my application using IHostedService that contains IHostApplicationLifetime in constructor

Constructor of class that I tried to test:

```
public Princess(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory, IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime, IOptions<OutputFilePrefix> options)
{
    _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
    Console.WriteLine(options.Value);
}
```

Test that crushed:

```
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<IContenderGenerator>(sp => stabGenerator);
services.AddScoped<IHall, Hall>();
services.AddScoped<IFriend, SimpleFriend>();
services.AddScoped<IResultSaver, FileResultSaver>();
services.AddHostedService<Princess>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();


var princess = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostedService>() as Princess;
Console.WriteLine(princess);
Assert.Greater(princess.ChooseContender().Rating, 10);
```

Stacktrace of error appeared:

```
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime' while attempting to activate 'pickyPride2.Princess'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites(Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, ParameterInfo[] parameters, Boolean throwIfCallSiteNotFound)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to manually add dependency of IHostApplicationLifetime but that doesn't work